# Matching specified text only outside specified html tags

Tags: regex

I've got a task in which I should capture specified text which cannot be between headline (of any size) and anchor html tags `(<h*></h*> and <a></a>)` nor inside tag as attribute.

For example I've got text:

```
<h1>TfL</h1>
<a href="tfl.gov.uk">Tfl</a>
TfL is official organization for keeping London moving.
```

Is it possible to match "TfL" only outside those tags using regular expressions?

Many thanks.

Peter.

Comment: It would be easier for you to use an HTML/XML/DOM parser then to use regexp.

Comment: Not sure what language you are using, but here is the stock answer for PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with selecting nodes using HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.SelectNodes() and then checking the node in selection if it is excluded tag or not and has or has not such parent (recursively).

```vb
Public Const cAlphabet As String = "AÁÄBCČDĎEÉĚFGHIÍJKLĹĽMNŇOÓÔPQRŔŘSŠTŤUÚŮVWXYÝZŽ0123456789" ' Accepted chars '

Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = nothing
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()

' div encapsulation is used for text which is not between any tags. '
' iHtmlText is variable which holds html document in text form '
doc.LoadHtml(String.Format("<div>{0}</div>", If(iHtmlText, String.Empty))) 

' "FIND_THIS_TEXT" can be any text which you want to find '
' Node selecting is case insensitive due to translate feature of xpath '
nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
        String.Format("//*[contains(translate(text(), '{0}', '{1}'), '{2}')]",
                      cAlphabet, cAlphabet.ToLower, "FIND_THIS_TEXT".ToLower))

For Each node As HtmlNode In nodes
   If (IsNotOrNestedInSpecifiedNode(node, "a", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6")) Then
       ' do something with the node here '
   End If
Next
```

IsNotOrNestedInSpecifiedNode function used in code above:

```vb
Private Function IsNotOrNestedInSpecifiedNode(ByVal iNode As HtmlNode, ByVal ParamArray iExcludedHtmlTags() As String) As Boolean
        Dim ret As Boolean = False

        If (iNode.Name.IsIn(iExcludedHtmlTags)) Then
            ret = False
        ElseIf (iNode.ParentNode IsNot Nothing) Then
            ret = IsNotOrNestedInSpecifiedNode(iNode.ParentNode, iExcludedHtmlTags)
        Else
            ret = True
        End If

        Return ret
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
(?<=<(h\d|a[^>].*?)>)(TfL)(?=</(h\d|a)>)
```

It will take all TfL-text from `<h*></h*>` and `<a></a>`